# how to rotate UI segmented control

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

hey all i want to know rotate the UI Segmented control to be in a vertical look

cheer

BOB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in this way.

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
[...]
segControl.transform = 
                CGAffineTransformRotate(segControl.transform, degreesToRadians(90));
```

if you want set correct position, remember that it consider the center of segControl!

ex:

```
segControl.frame = CGRectMake(-125, 220, 320, 30);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done something like that before but I think one approach could be to subclass UISegmented control and use Affine Transforms related functions inside the Core Graphics framework, there you use for example CGContextRotateCTM() to give a 90 degrees rotation.
Hope this helps.